# Submit button wont change on hover

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to get the donate button to change on hover in the following site http://laceibamfi.org/.

The CSS i am using won't respond on hover. I really don't know what to do.

What I want is:

```
<input type="submit" value="Donate Now!" name="Submit" id="theButton">
```

To have a hover affect, this is what I currently have for CSS:

```
#theButton {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #73752b !important;
    border-radius: 13px;
    border-top: 1px solid #d4d117;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Georgia,serif;
    font-size: 24px !important;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Working JSFiddle for what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/bxm2wnyd/1/

Comment: show your code, make it people easy to help you

Comment: Show some html/css/javascript

Comment: This will show you how to apply a style change using CSS on hover: http://jsfiddle.net/7ms5fzse/

Comment: Your question doesn't meet the requirements of asking a question on this site.  Please read the rules before participating, it will make people more willing to assist you.

Comment: As a note, this appears to be a cascade issue. As a dirty answer, add !important after the background colour and border updates on hover. Otherwise, spend more time in dev tools and work out what styles are taking precedence and update your selectors appropriately.

Comment: [:hover selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), [:active selector, for when clicked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't called the :hover selector.

If you are using CSS, create a new block like so

```
#theButton:hover {
  selector: property
}
```

If you are using SASS you can call &:hover inside the id element

```
#theButton {
  ...
  ...
  &:hover {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the [:hover selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) on your button. Then you would put the properties you want to have happen when the button is hovered:

```
#theButton {
  /* your properties here */
}
```